# Верхняя часть WP-сайта не отображается с мобильных устройств, хотя при просмотре через инспекторный эмулятор все норм, почему?

Tags: html, адаптивная-верстка

Появилась проблема следующего характера.

При просмотра сайта с мобильных устройств, почему-то не видно его значительную верхнюю часть и страница как-бы начинается с половины. При этом, когда просматриваю сайт в devtools режиме, включаю эмулятор мобильных девайсов и показывает все нормально, как и должно быть.

Пробовал также не стандартные браузерные эмуляторы, а всякие другие найденные в сети, однако проблему решить это не помогло. Через все эмуляторы сайт показывается должным образом, а через мобильные - криво.

То есть, видя проблему при просмотре с мобильного девайса, я даже не могу посмотреть через инспектор кода, ибо на мобиле devtools не включишь. А когда смотрю через эмулятор - там можно инспектировать код, при просмотре через них - проблему не видно и все отображается корректно.

Что делать, как быть?

Это скрин с инспектора, тут страница начинается с самого начала, как нужно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А это скрин с телефона. Тут страница начинается со середины и выше не прокручивается, хотя должна.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Было бы хорошо получить ссылку на сайт или на тестовую среду. Посмотреть, потыкать. Я думаю что-то с медиа-запросами.
Инструменты есть вот тут, https://www.browserstack.com/ платный инструмент но есть триал для вашего случая. Можно эмулировать почти любой браузер. Сам постоянно пользуюсь, не реклама!

Comment: А можно вам на почту ссылку скинуть?
Не хотелось бы публично ей делиться.

Comment: lyfat@getnada.com, пишите

Comment: Написал на почту вам. Спасибо большое за участие!

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрел сайт, варианты решения:

1. На странице есть блок со стилями 
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   попробуйте удалить или закомментировать его и посмотреть что получиться.
2. Можно отключить JavaScript, посмотреть как будет работать все него, но страница может поехать.

По стилям везде натыкан флекс, и выравнивания от него, я больше всего склоняюсь к тому что **именно он** двигает разметку.
+ к этому в структуре вложенные элементы которые не принимают родительских свойств ширины, прокрутки, и тд а имеют свою высоту например для блока. Высота блоков должна строиться относительно контента который в нем находиться за исключением например скрола внутри блока.

Если у Вас покупная тема и в ней есть еще шаблоны одиночных страниц, попробуйте их, это указывается при редактировании страницы в правом сайдбаре.

Баг повторяется на внутренних страницах, потому что для них используется отельный шаблон Simple Page.

**Вывод:** Сам текст есть на странице но он поднят выше, на втором скрине видно кусочек текста после шапки который Вы замазали. Блок высотой 1800px и все что вы не видите выше за границей экрана. Скорее всего это флекс из-за его выравнивания и поведения, я бы стал копать в эту сторону.

Comment: Благодарю вас за помощь, теперь хотя бы примерно представляю в каком направлении двигаться. Буду пробовать.